# jQuery result not showing unless I press the 'back' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, back

I've got a strange problem in that my function is working as it should (a jQuery sweepstake generator) but it doesn't display output unless I press the back button on the browser. The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[name=Submit]").click(function() {
    var x = $("input[name=playerNumber]").val();
    var y = $("input[name=teamNumber]").val();
    var playerArray = new Array(x);
    var teamArray   = new Array(y);
    var areaToAddTo = $('#playerArea');
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        playerArray[i] = prompt("What is the name of player "+(i+1)+"?");
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        teamArray[j] = prompt("What is the name of team "+(j+1)+"?");
    }
    var teamsToLeaveOut = teamArray.length % playerArray.length;
    var count = 0;
    var randomNumber;
    while (count < teamsToLeaveOut) {
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(teamArray.length));
        teamArray.splice(randomNumber, 1);
        count++;
    }
    count = teamArray.length;
    var spliceTeam;
    var l;
    while (count > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < playerArray.length; i++) {
            randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*teamArray.length);
            spliceTeam = teamArray[randomNumber];
            l += ('<h3>'+playerArray[i]+'</h3>');
            l += ('<p>'+spliceTeam+'</p>');
            teamArray.splice(randomNumber,1);
            count--;
        }
    }
    if (1 == 1) {
        areaToAddTo.append(l);
    }
});
});
```

On running the function nothing is written to the screen and the browser url is:
`/sweepstake.html?playerNumber=2&teamNumber=5&Submit=Submit`

On pressing the back button the output is as it should be and the browser url is:
`/sweepstake.html`

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `input[name=Submit]` an actual submit button? If so, looks like you're actually posting your form, when you don't want to. You can `return false` to both prevent the default action (in this case, processing the click on the button) and stop propagation (thereby preventing the event from bubbling up the DOM).

Comment: @JBRTRND Well, there are special cases when 1 is not equal to 1. Like when 1 is redefined, or something.

Comment: if (1 == 1) was just a (futile) attempt to get it to stay on screen.

input[name=Submit] is a submit button, would I be better changing that to a button and having the jQuery act on a button click instead of a submit button click?

Comment: If you want to pause an execution to examine the result, use `alert` - it'll wait for your input. Don't commit to the ways of Chtulhu. )

Comment: The back button is probably faulty.

Comment: @raina77ow I don't think we are in front of a "special case".

Comment: Special cases are sudden, @JBRTRND!

Comment: @raina77ow And I'm afraid of them..

Comment: after submission use, window.history.go(-1) to force a back click.

Comment: @DexterHuinda `window.history.go(-1)` is quite a cool way of doing things actually. I suppose the best way is going to be to have the jQuery attached to a non-input button though the `return false` thing works too.

Comment: yes the `return false` is always the best way to halt normal execution of things in the binary world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is being submitted, prevent the submission and you won't have to go back to it.

```
    ...
    if (1 == 1) { // ??
        areaToAddTo.append(l);
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: I like how this answer still contains that sanity check. Indeed, it's no use to append something to something if 1 is no longer equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comments, the browser is trying to submit the form, which takes you to a new url, which is not what you want. Either use a plain old button instead to kick off your function, or prevent the default submit behavior by returning false in the last line of your handler.

Comment: It's not **trying** to submit the form, it's succeeding.

Comment: what I meant by submit is: sending data to a server, which is then processed there, which does not seem to be what you want to do.